# Error registering camel's ftp jpa Idempotent repository

Tags: jmx, apache-camel, idempotent

I'm trying to implement jpa idempotent repository just as described here http://camel.apache.org/file2.html, but i'm getting a Mbean export error.

On my application-context.xml i've the following section.

```
<bean id="mvStore" class="org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jpa.JpaMessageIdRepository" lazy-init="false">
        <!-- Here we refer to the spring jpaTemplate -->
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="jpaTemplate" />
        <!-- This 2nd parameter is the name (= a cateogry name). You can have different repositories with different names -->
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="FileConsumer" />
    </bean>
<context:mbean-server id="mbeanServer" />
<context:mbean-export server="mbeanServer" registration="replaceExisting" default-domain="br.com.touchtec"/>
```

If I remove the above section than the server (tomcat) starts just fine. Can anybody help me on this?

Here's the stack:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.apache.camel.processor.idempotent.jpa.JpaMessageIdRepository@6df960c4] with key 'mvStore'; nested exception is javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Key properties cannot be empty
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:602)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:527)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterPropertiesSet(MBeanExporter.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 50 more

Caused by: javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Key properties cannot be empty
    at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:467)
    at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(ObjectName.java:1403)
    at javax.management.ObjectName.getInstance(ObjectName.java:1285)
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.ObjectNameManager.getInstance(ObjectNameManager.java:62)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.MetadataNamingStrategy.getObjectName(MetadataNamingStrategy.java:114)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.getObjectName(MBeanExporter.java:728)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:631)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:592)
    ... 54 more
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I hope you're clear on the fact the jmx part is not necessary to make the Idempotent Repository work. Your error is a pure JMX/Spring error, not linked to Camel.

If you want to use an MBeanExporter, you should read the official documentation on [Spring JMX](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html) to have a better understaking of this matter.

Your MBeanExporter definition might look like

```
<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
    <property name="beans">
      <map>
        <entry key="bean:name=mvStore" value-ref="mvStore"/>
      </map>
    </property>
    <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: Yes, i'm aware. however my configuration looks just like the 22.4.3 section of the oficial documentation, and it was working before i put the camel idempotent bean. So, why does this happen? shouldn't camel's class be smart enough to work on the default spring-jmx config?